# Opening wsltty in a directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, mintty

If in Windows 10 I type `wsl`, `ubuntu` or `cmd` in the address bar of a directory, the relevant console is opened in that directory; is there a way to open the same way mintty/wsltty? I tried putting a shortcut and a symbolic link to wsltty.exe in system32, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution just after opening the bounty: I made an AHK exe that runs `Run %LOCALAPPDATA%\wsltty\bin\mintty.exe --WSL="Ubuntu" --configdir="%APPDATA%\wsltty"` and placed it in system32.